# Jquery changed div id, functioning executing on old div id not the changed

Tags: jquery

I changed my div id from 1 tot 2.

```
<div id="1"></div>
```

```js
$('#id1').attr('id', '2');
```

NEW :

```
<div id="2"></div>
```

I use this Jquery :

```
$("#1").click(function() {
$("#2").click(function() {
```

However after the id has changed and I click it, it still executes the JQuery function for #id1 click.

It should be the Jquery for the changed div which is now2, so Jquery function #id 2 click.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense: `$('#id1')`.

Comment: I think you're looking for `$('#1')` instead.

Comment: Apart from the observation by @MelanciaUK; you should also delegate your selector. The ID=2 element doesn't exist when the body is ready.

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense. Do you have a fiddle?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: And the typo is still there after your edit.

Comment: Change any attribute as class but not the ID, doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However after the id has changed and I click it, it still executes the JQuery function for #id1 click.

This is because the element is still the same one which existed in the DOM wi an id of `1`, all that has changed is it's identifying property. If you want to remove the event handler on an element, use `off()`.

```
<div id="1"></div>
```

```js
$('#id1').click(function() {
    alert('foo');
}).attr('id', '2');

$('#id2').off('click').click(function() {
    alert('bar');
});
```

In this example, clicking the `div` would result in *only* `bar` being displayed in an alert as the call to `off()` removed the first handler showing `foo`.

Comment: This seems to be the answer, thanks. Do you maybe have a small example for me ?

Comment: @user3710844 just added one for you.

Comment: Basically what you are saying is that I also need to change it in the DOM ?

Comment: @user3710844 [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)...

Comment: Thanks, if I understand it right. This will put the click function off. Right ?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. After checking the Jquery docs, I found this : The .off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on(). We never attached anything with on right ?

Comment: You attached using `click` which is a shortcut for `on`.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's handlers attached to the element(s) that matched the selector at the time. Changing the IDs, classes, etc. doesn't remove the handlers (or move them to other elements).

To achieve the effect you want (always applying based on ID at the time), use `.on()`:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#id1', function() {
  // do something whenever the current #id1 element is clicked
});

$(document.body).on('click', '#id2', function() {
  // do something whenever the current #id2 element is clicked
});
```

Comment: To be honest, I dont know which solution is better yours or Rory's.

Comment: It depends on how you select your elements. If you can use a common class then you only need one delegated handler so use this method. If you *have* to select by unique `id`, then you'd probably be better with my method.